# what is the worth of Assembly Language

Tags: assembly

i am a student of computer Science,
Why assembly language in our courses, what is the worth of it,
what is the scope of this language,
in which fields this language is used?

Comment: Stackoverflow site is used to help solving particular problems on particular source codes that members upload rather than answering the kind of questions that you state. Perhaps programmers.stackexchange.com (a sister site of this one) is more suited for your question.

Comment: ok thanx,
i did'nt know that...

Comment: No offense, by why don't you ask your professor?

Comment: When your high level language program misbehaves in some inexplicable way, not often, but in rare cases it's because there's a bug in the compiler. Being able to understand the assembly language generated by the compiler can help figure that out. Many visual language debuggers display the assembly language as a debug tool.

Comment: Assembly language can be a great tool. In particular, it allows you to understand which parts of your program a compiler has difficulty optimizing. If you can read the compiler generated assembly, often small changes to your higher-level source-code can help the compiler produce vastly improved code.

Comment: @Blechdose i had asked my teacher, but their answer was not satisfied me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every other programming language you use either compiles to assembly and then gets assembled into machine code or sometimes it compiles straight to machine code.  Granted some languages compile first to some sort of bytecode (java for example) and then there is a virtual machine of some sort that interpretes and executes the bytecode.  That virtual machine or interpreter or whatever ultimately runs machine code via a program that was likely compiled to assembly then into machine code.

The processor(s) in computers only run machine code, and assembly, ideally , has a one to one relationship with machine code.  So by learning assembly you are actually learning how the processor works.

Where would a programmer who does not write or debug compilers or assemblers or processors use assembly language?  if you have performance reasons and can justify it you may wish to take compile code and improve it by hand or hand code routines for performance reasons (do a better job that the compiler).  Folks that use microcontrollers are possibly one of the last places where you may still see a lot of assembly used for the whole project.  a lot of that is moving to C or other languages but you still find projects for small microcontrollers that are all assembly.  And there are folks that do it for fun.

Comment: thanx, but now adays, where it is used?

Comment: it is used as the output of many compilers (the compiler itself, the program you normally call calls the compiler the assembler and the linker).  It is used for toolchain development testing, processor development and testing (silicon/hardware), and used for microcontrollers sometimes and used for performance (video games, scientific applications, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Assembly language is mostly used when writing software that works closely with hardware, like device drivers, or software that needs to be highly optimised.

One of the reasons for learning assembly language is that it relates directly to the machine code instructions that other languages compile into. By knowing a bit about what the simplest building blocks are, you know more about what other programming languages can be capable of, and which operations are more or less demanding for the processor.

Comment: thanx, but now adays, where it is used?

Comment: @Nascent: There is still a need for device drivers, and optimised code for example as a part of game programming.

Answer (score 1):

What is the worth of assembly? -- In short **understanding**. In addition to the other response, the number 1 reason to take a course in assembly is to gain hardware level knowledge of how code tells hardware what to do. With all high-level languages, most of the actual machine interaction is lost (even with C). What you will learn through assembly is how programming actually interacts with hardware at the most fundamental level (aside from pure machine language). You gain intimate knowedge of the processor, the registers, the actual system-calls that make things work, along with the calling conventions that allow high-level language to interface with assembler.

There is no substitute for the level of understanding you will gain by studying assembly. If you plan on a career in programming, it is the cornerstone that all other languages are built on.

If you have the option to take a course -- take it, you won't regret it.

Comment: thanx, but now adays, where it is used?

Comment: It is used to supplement many languages, including `C`, when you need to do something the language doesn't provide (e.g. rotate bits), or when you need a faster/more optimized way of solving a problem (e.g. most significant bit). There are endless ways it can be used directly, but by far the most (where is it used) answer - is in teaching you to write more robust and efficient code -- regardless of what language you are writing in -- because you understand how the code with ultimately be used by the hardware. (Its direct use is now primarly embedded systems)